# ReadProcessMemory returning wrong values

Tags: delphi, winapi

To me the code looks okay, maybe the address is being read wrong. I do get values returned but definitely the wrong values. Have tried with `VirtualProtectEx` but still get the same values returned.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  hProc, Read, hwnd: THandle;
  Pid, Addr1, Addr2, Addr3: Cardinal;
  First,Middle,Last: DWORD;
  //oldprot, tmp: DWORD;
begin
  Addr1:=$FD3325ACA8; //10 value at address
  Addr2:=$FD33258CEC; //100 value at address
  Addr3:=$FD3325DA00; //1000 value at address
  hwnd:=FindWindow('notepad',nil);
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, Pid);
  hProc := OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, False, Pid);
  if hProc > 0 then
  begin
    //VirtualProtectEx(hProc, pointer(addr1), 4, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, @oldprot);
    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, pointer(addr1), @First, SizeOf(First), Read);
    Edit1.Text := IntToStr(First); //2059264 value returned
    //VirtualProtectEx(hProc, pointer(addr1), 4, oldprot, @tmp);
    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, pointer(addr2), @Middle, SizeOf(Middle), Read);
    Edit2.Text := IntToStr(Middle); //1900544 value returned
    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, pointer(addr3), @Last, SizeOf(Last), Read);
    Edit3.Text := IntToStr(Last); //9899526 value returned
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Use [`Win32Check`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SysUtils.Win32Check), Luke!

Comment: Thanks! Got it working using `Win32Check` around `ReadProcessMemory`. Problem was the addresses i was using were pointers and static addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to recognise is the `ReadProcessMemory` works correctly. When it succeeds, it returns the correct values.

Here are the possible explanations for the behaviour that you observe;

1. One of the API calls is failing. You cannot know this because you don't check. Because the API calls fail, the values of your three `DWORD` variables are never initialized.
2. The API calls succeed and the values returned by `ReadProcessMemory` are indeed the contents of those memory locations.

The next step is to check for errors. Add error checking for each and every API call. Consult the documentation to find out how to do it.

And note that the only error checking that you perform at the moment is semantically incorrect. When `OpenProcess` fails it returns `0`. So test for success by the condition of the process handle being not-equal to `0`. The use of greater than here implies that sign is important.

For any functions that call `SetLastError`, you can make good use of `Win32Check`:

```
hProc := OpenProcess(...);
Win32Check(hProc <> 0);
```

This will raise an OS error with descriptive text in case the condition evaluates false.

Comment: Thanks. I was using `ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));` but was getting operation was successful. The `Win32Check` worked wonders!

Comment: You cannot call GetLastError indiscriminately. Only do so if the docs tell you to. Typically that is only when the function fails, indicated through its return value. And error handling varies. So you need to consult the docs function by function.